# Electron, react and parcel application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm currently trying to compile my electron application into a dist for mac.  I am using the boilerplate found here https://github.com/kumarryogeshh/electron-react-parcel-boilerplate

Currently trying to modularise parts of the code, specifically looking at the electron side of things. So the intention is to have the following structure.

```
- src 
  - components 
  - electron_components 
      window.js 
  electron.js 
  App.js 
  custom.css 
  index.js
```

My application is going to have multiple windows, therefore having the `windows.js` class makes sense, see below:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { BrowserWindow } = electron;
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

class Window extends BrowserWindow {
  constructor(urldev, urlLive, height, width, resizable = true, parent = null, modal = false) {
    super({
      height: height,
      width: width,
      frame: true,
      resizable: resizable,
      show: true,
      parent: parent,
      modal: modal,
      webPreferences: {
                        //allows application to run in the background
                        backgroundThrottling: true,
                        nodeIntegration: true
                        }
    });
    let promise = this.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? urldev
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, urlLive)}`
  );
  }
}

module.exports = Window;
```

The `electron.js` file is below:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;

const path = require("path");
const window = require(path.join(__dirname, './electron_components/window'))

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new window('http://localhost:3000', "./build/index.html", 800, 600)
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

So when I run the application by the command `yarn start` it runs and works. This is because it is the development environment.  However, when I build the dist, by running `yarn build` it comes up with the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/electron-react-parcel 1.0.0 1/electron-react-parcel.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/electron_components/window'
Require stack:
- /Volumes/electron-react-parcel 1.0.0 1/electron-react-parcel.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/electron.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:17)
    at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:7736:16)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:738:28)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:738:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/electron-react-parcel 1.0.0 1/electron-react-parcel.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/electron.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
```

Obviously something is going wrong with the component importation and therefore safe to assume that the import statement for the `window class` at the top of the `electron.js` file isn't right. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but your assistance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with parcel but I setup a repository for using electron react with typescript https://github.com/plixxer/electron-react let me know if this helps. If you are trying an academic exorcise im sure you can do a diff.

Answer (score 0):

So I chose to change to a different boilerplate that used electron forge. Whilst not answering the original question. It rectified my issue.